# How to correctly describe a golang struct using swagger?

Tags: api, go, swagger, swagger-codegen, hapi-swagger

I have some problem. In different sites you can find how to correctly describe go struct using swagger(annotations).
Example:

```
// swagger:model
type User struct {
    // the id for this user
    //
    // required: true
    // min: 1
    ID int64 `json:"id"`

    // the name for this user
    // required: true
    // min length: 3
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

But can someone help me with, how to describe go struct that is in the method and isn't public?
And what I should to enter in @Param field after description for successful generation docs?
Example:

```
func (n *newStruct) GetPetInfo(c *gin.Context){
info := struct {
    PetId  uint64 `form:"petId" json:"petId"`
    Sl     uint64 `form:"sl" json:"sl"`
}{}

...

}
```

Help me please with this situation)